# How can I filter dynamically Json object? My filter condition can be changeable. There are too many situations

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I want to filter my data to dynamically. But our condition must be dynamic. I wanna call this method on the `<select (change)="filterData($event.target.value,'jobStatusId')" >` However, `jobStatusId` can be change. It can be `jobTypeId`. How can I make it dynamic.

I try this, for example I have a data like this;
`

```
filteredData= [
     {
      "jobStatusId": 1,
      "jobTypeId": 2,
      "jobPriorityId": 3,

     },
     {
      "jobStatusId": 2,
      "jobTypeId": 3,
      "jobPriorityId": 3,
     },
     {
      "jobStatusId": 2,
      "jobTypeId": 3,
      "jobPriorityId": 4,
     }
]
```

Also I write a method like;

```
filterData(id, condition: string) {
    this.filteredData = this.filteredData.filter(
      (a) => a.condition === id
    );
  }
```

In this method, let's focus `condition: string`. `condition` can be `jobStatusId` or `jobTypeId` or `jobPriorityId`. I wanna make it dynamic.

For example;
When I call like, `filterData(2,jobStatusId)`
my data should be:

```
     {
      "jobStatusId": 2,
      "jobTypeId": 3,
      "jobPriorityId": 3,
     },
     {
      "jobStatusId": 2,
      "jobTypeId": 3,
      "jobPriorityId": 4,
     }
```

If I call it twice like:

```
filterData(2,jobStatusId)
filterData(4,jobPriorityId)
```

Then, my filteredData should be:

```
     {
      "jobStatusId": 2,
      "jobTypeId": 3,
      "jobPriorityId": 4,
     }
```

How can I make it dynamic? How can I make it like that? If you have better solution, you can tell me. However I wanna call this method on the `<select (change)="filterData($event.target.value,'jobStatusId')" >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a type based of your javascript object like this:

```js
// somewhere in your project
export type JobType = 'jobTypeId' | 'jobStatusId' | 'jobPriorityId';
```

Then, the condition is going to be of type `JobType`

```js
filterData(id: number, condition: JobType): void {   
  const filtered = this.filteredData.filter(d => d[condition] === id);
  return filtered;
}
```

In the template HTML, you need to send the exact value that matches any `JobType` value, otherwise, `Typescript` will complain:

```html
<!-- works -->
<select (change)=filtered($event.target.value, 'jobStatusId') >

<!-- doesn't work -->
<select (change)=filtered($event.target.value, 'invalid-value') >
```